# Convergent Series: $\sqrt{n+1}/(n^2 + 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this homework problem that I'm having difficulty on.

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2+2}
> $$

I've found that the series is most likely convergent by the divergent test. As using lhospitals rule, the sequence approaches 0, thus it MIGHT be a convergent series. However, I do think it's convergent because it doesn't appear to be a harmonic sequence. So now I need to find the sum of the series, and that's where I am having trouble with.

Comment: The series is in fact convergent, you just need to compare the general term with $1/n^{\alpha}$, with convenient $\alpha$. This is a very basic exercise, you should try to do it yourself before asking for the solution in a forum, otherwise you will not learn much from this.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  I noticed the title has $n^2+1$ but the question has $n^2+2$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Compute the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2+1}}{\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}}.$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you got there, could you please elaborate?

Comment: That limit is a real number greater than $0$. Therefore, either both series are convergent or they both diverge.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n\ge1$, we have the estimate

$$0<\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2+2}\le \frac{\sqrt{n+n}}{n^2}=\frac{\sqrt2}{n^{3/2}} $$

Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^{3/2}}$ converges, the series of interest, $\sum_{n\ge1 }\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n^2+2}$ does likewise.